# Do orbiting bodies consume energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

Since orbiting bodies are under constant acceleration, this means they are experiencing force.  Considering `work = force X distance` and work is energy, where does this energy come from?

I understand the *force* is supplied by gravity, but this *work* does not seem to 'use up' the gravity.

Thinking about this, I am assuming potential energy is being converted into kinetic energy...yet we don't seem to be consuming the potential energy, so I must be misunderstanding something.

If this could be illustrated with some math, or even a simple analogy, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a force not do any work if it's perpendicular to the motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310104/)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462768/do-orbiting-planets-have-infinite-energy/462780#462780

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force and infinitesimal displacement are vectors. When computing work as

$$W=\int\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{ds}$$

you have to take their dot product. The dot product is zero when they are perpendicular, positive when they make an angle of less than 90 degrees, and negative when they make an angle of more than 90 degrees.

In a circular orbit, the force is radial and the displacement is tangential. So they are always perpendicular and the work done on the planet is zero.

In an elliptical orbit, they aren’t perpendicular, except at perihelion and aphelion. But for the part of the orbit where the planet is moving closer the Sun, the work is positive, and for the part where the planet is movng father from the Sun, the work is negative. The net work done by the Sun’s gravity on the planet over one revolution is zero.

When the planet moves closer, it loses potential energy and gains an equal amount of kinetic energy. When it moves farther away, it gains potential energy and loses kinetic energy. The total energy stays constant.

Thus planets *do not* consume energy.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, another way to put it would be that since the force is perpendicular to the motion, and this distance doesn't change...going back to work =  force X distance....distance is zero, so work is zero?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: The planet is moving tangentially and it has a nonzero displacement $\mathbf{ds}$. But for a circular orbit, it has no component of displacement *in the direction of the force*.

Comment: If you have been taught that work is force times distance, realize that this is a one-dimensional simplification. If you haven’t learned about dot products yet, think “work is force times distance-in-the-direction-of-the-force” or “work is force-in-the-direction-of-the-distance times distance”.

Comment: This snaps it together for me.  I had been taught only that work is force times distance.  I have not learned about dot products yet, but I am now studying it, thanks to you!  This was beyond helpful!

Comment: Great! I’m glad to have been of help. Would you like to mark my answer as accepted with the check mark icon?

Answer (score 3):

Orbiting bodies move under the influence of gravity on circular or elliptic orbits. The central body that exerts the force on the orbiting body sits at one of the focal points of the ellipse.

The easiest way to understand the interplay between kinetic and potential energy along such an orbit is to realize that the potential energy increases radially from the central body with increasing distance. If you look in the plane of the elliptic orbits, lines of constant pontential are circles. During the course of its motion, if the orbiting body comes closer to the central body, it reduces its potential energy in the gravitational field, i.e., the gravitational force performs acceleration-work on the orbiting body. This work, or loss in potential energy is converted into kinetic energy, i.e., the body gets faster. After moving through the point of the orbit closest to the central body, the orbiting body increases its distance from the central body again, which increases its potential energy in the gravitational field at the cost of kinetic energy, so the work conserved in the form of kinetic energy is given back.

In total, energy is conserved during this kind of motion, because the involved gravitational force is a *conservative force*. A conservative force $\vec{F}$ can be expressed as the gradient of position ($\vec{r}$) dependent potential energy $V(\vec{r})$, i.e,
$$ \vec{F} = -\nabla V(\vec{r}).$$

If you start from Newton's equation of motion
$$ m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \vec{F} = -\nabla V, $$
you multiply both sides of the equation with velocity $\vec{v}$, you obtain on the left hand side
$$ m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\vec{v} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}^2\right),$$
and on the right hand side
$$ -\nabla V\cdot \vec{v} = -\frac{d}{dt}V(\vec{r}),$$
such that
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m\vec{v}^2 + V(\vec{r})\right) = 0.$$
This means that for conservative forces, the sum of kinetic and potential energies is always time-independent, i.e., conserved. All a mechanical system can do in such a situation is to shuffle energy back and forth between kinetic and potential energy. They cannot consume energy (in physics we would say, they do not dissipate energy).

This is what happens during orbital motion in a gravitational field, where the potential energy is given by
$$ V(\vec{r})\propto -\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|},$$
if the central body sits in the origin.